# How to stub Nokogiri in spec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, nokogiri

How to stub Nokogiri in fetch method of PromoDate in RSpec

```
 class PromoDate

      def self.fetch_data(request)
         page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{request.host}#{url}")) 
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you should not only stub Nokogiri::HTML but also "open" method, so you can do smth like this:

```
expect(PromoDate).to receive(:open).and_return(File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/page_for_parsing.html"))
expect(Nokogiri::HTML::Document).to receive(:parse).and_return(whatever_you_want)
```

Where page_for_parsing.html is html page created in fixtures folder for testing purpose.
Nokogiri::HTML is just a convenience method for Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse, you can see it in [source code](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/html.rb)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's more OpenURI you need to stub than Nokogiri itself.

You could do it easily with the [Mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) gem.

```
fake_html = <<-EOS
  <html>
    <head><title>Some Title</title></head>
    <body>Some Content</body>
  </html>
EOS
PromoDate.any_instance.stubs(:open).returns(fake_html)
```

You can also make sure in that test that this function is called with the right parameter:

```
PromoDate.any_instance.expects(:open).with('http://www.google.com').returns(fake_html)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allow(Nokogiri::HTML::Document).to \
receive(:parse).with(open("#{request.host}#{url}").body, \
nil, nil, Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML\
).and_return(your_fakeresponse_body)
```

Credit to @kaleb4eg for identifying the correct method class and method to address.

Answer (score 0):

```
PromoDate.send(:define_method, :open) { |*args| "" }
allow(promoDateobj::Nokogiri).to receive(:XML).with(anything).and_return(whatever_you_want)
```

Try it. I have applied it and it works fine for me.